# Android emulator failing to install any apk file and showing android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-service, connection-leaks

I am getting following error when trying to run any android applications in emulator with **Android API 4.2(17)** in **eclipse ADT** .Earlier my apps were running fine,but this problem started after restarting my machine.

```
[2013-03-25 18:25:42 - MyHapiSample] Failed to install MyHapiSample.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
[2013-03-25 18:25:42 - MyHapiSample] (null)
[2013-03-25 18:25:53 - MyHapiSample] Launch canceled!
```

The logcat is showing following errors

```
 03-25 11:42:39.838: E/ActivityThread(632): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d293d8 that was originally bound here
 03-25 11:42:39.838: E/ActivityThread(632): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d293d8 that was originally bound here
 03-25 11:42:39.838: E/ActivityThread(632):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
 03-25 11:42:39.838: E/ActivityThread(632):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
 03-25 11:42:39.838: E/ActivityThread(632):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
 03-25 11:42:39.838: E/ActivityThread(632):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
 03-25 11:42:39.838: E/ActivityThread(632):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
 03-25 11:42:39.838: E/ActivityThread(632):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
 03-25 11:42:39.838: E/ActivityThread(632):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
 03-25 11:42:39.838: E/ActivityThread(632):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
 03-25 11:42:39.838: E/ActivityThread(632):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
 03-25 11:42:39.838: E/ActivityThread(632):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
 03-25 11:42:39.838: E/ActivityThread(632):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
 03-25 11:42:39.838: E/ActivityThread(632):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
 03-25 11:42:39.838: E/ActivityThread(632):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
 03-25 11:42:39.838: E/ActivityThread(632):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
 03-25 11:42:39.838: E/ActivityThread(632):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
 03-25 11:42:39.838: E/ActivityThread(632):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
 03-25 11:42:39.856: E/StrictMode(632): null
 03-25 11:42:39.856: E/StrictMode(632): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d293d8 that was originally bound here
 03-25 11:42:39.856: E/StrictMode(632):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
 03-25 11:42:39.856: E/StrictMode(632):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
 03-25 11:42:39.856: E/StrictMode(632):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
 03-25 11:42:39.856: E/StrictMode(632):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
 03-25 11:42:39.856: E/StrictMode(632):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
 03-25 11:42:39.856: E/StrictMode(632):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
 03-25 11:42:39.856: E/StrictMode(632):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
 03-25 11:42:39.856: E/StrictMode(632):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
 03-25 11:42:39.856: E/StrictMode(632):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
 03-25 11:42:39.856: E/StrictMode(632):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
 03-25 11:42:39.856: E/StrictMode(632):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
 03-25 11:42:39.856: E/StrictMode(632):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
 03-25 11:42:39.856: E/StrictMode(632):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
 03-25 11:42:39.856: E/StrictMode(632):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
 03-25 11:42:39.856: E/StrictMode(632):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
 03-25 11:42:39.856: E/StrictMode(632):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
 03-25 11:42:39.875: W/ActivityManager(287): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@40e7cc50
 03-25 11:42:39.885: D/dalvikvm(632): GC_CONCURRENT freed 484K, 20% free 2472K/3084K, paused 74ms+7ms, total 175ms
 03-25 11:43:00.025: W/Trace(287): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
 03-25 11:43:00.025: W/Trace(287): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
 03-25 11:43:00.038: W/Trace(287): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
 03-25 11:43:00.044: W/Trace(556): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
 03-25 11:43:00.065: W/Trace(287): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
 03-25 11:43:00.099: W/Trace(816): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
 03-25 11:43:00.124: W/Trace(816): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
 03-25 11:43:00.138: W/Trace(556): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
 03-25 11:43:00.138: W/Trace(556): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
 03-25 11:43:00.138: W/Trace(556): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
 03-25 11:43:00.146: W/Trace(816): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
 03-25 11:43:00.146: W/Trace(816): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
 03-25 11:43:00.164: W/Trace(816): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
 03-25 11:43:00.174: W/Trace(816): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
 03-25 11:43:00.174: W/Trace(816): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
 03-25 11:43:00.174: W/Trace(816): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
 03-25 11:43:00.204: W/Trace(816): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
 03-25 11:43:00.204: W/Trace(816): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
 03-25 11:43:00.225: W/Trace(816): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
 03-25 11:43:00.283: W/Trace(816): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
 03-25 11:43:00.285: W/Trace(816): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
 03-25 11:43:00.285: W/Trace(816): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
 03-25 11:43:00.344: W/Trace(816): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
 03-25 11:43:00.374: W/Trace(816): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
 03-25 11:43:00.374: W/Trace(816): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
 03-25 11:43:00.374: W/Trace(816): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
 : E/(): Device disconnected
```

Did some settings get changed for android and do I have to reinstall eclipse?

I am clueless what the android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked  means or what is causing this error and desperately looking for help.

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992676/i-cant-get-rid-of-this-error-message-activity-app-name-has-leaked-servicecon

Comment: @SergeyBenner Thanks for the suggestion.I could fix my problem after going through it.

Answer (score 0):

I could fix the error following the suggestions from the link suggested by  Sergey Benner.I was having some issues with the emulator and third party jar files.When I recreated the device emulators i could fix the errors and my app is running properly.